# Slowing down animations in Flutter globally

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

There is *a function or method* in the **Flutter framework**, which can be used to ajust the animation/running speed of every widget.

This is *possible* using I think a **service**.

I just forgot how I can call it and could not find any *resources* that describe it + I do not know where I once discovered it.

There is not really more information to *provide* as this is just a *simple **one liner***. I hope that someone knows what I am talking about.

Comment: do you mean the slow [motion option](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/options.dart#L300]) in the flutter Gallery app ?

Comment: @RaoufRahiche I could have looked at that source if I knew about it :) I wanted to say that I knew about `timeDilation` some time back, but forgot the package and property names :)

Comment: Can we use the timeDilation property to control the feedback of Draggable when it is not accepted by the DropTarget?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need set the `timeDilation` static property:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
// you can also import the whole file:
// import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart'; 

...

timeDilation = 2.0; // Will slow down animations by a factor of two
```

I am using **`show`** in my `import` because it limits the import to certain declarations from the library. 
In this context I only want to be able to use `timeDilation` from the *`scheduler.dart` library*, and nothing else. Since schedulers are pretty low-level things, this makes sense to not *pollute the namespace*. There's also `hide` that has the opposite effect (only hides certain declarations).

You can set this from anywhere in your app, even in the main function:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

void main() {
  timeDilation = 3.0;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

or in your pressed handler:

```
onPressed: () => timeDilation = 2.0
```

This is a global static property so you don't need to call `setState` in order for the changes to take place.

Comment: >  it should be very obvious that setState does not need to be called -- maybe for you, not for everyone; > Animations are not connected to state -- animations are connected to the state, scheduling isn't, isn't that right? > I think that onPressed is a strange addition. Maybe remove that -- I'm sorry that my answer contains more information than just `timeDilation` from 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart'`. I think an example is useful for people looking for information about time dilation in general. Why is it too much and explaining `show` isn't?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean it in a negative way. I just think that some parts were strange, e.g. `onPressed` is completely out of context and I still do not know what  `show` does in your code :) You asked about scheduling and yes that is of course what I tried to say because that is the part of the animation that makes it an animation. Gave you an upvote now, but I still want to know what `show` does :) I do not want you to explain the concept of `show`, it would just be nice to explain why you chose to include it (I mean it is obvious if you know what it does).

Comment: Sorry if I came out overtly negative as well, I just wanted the answer to be more accessible somehow. As for `show`, it limits import to certain declarations from the library -- in this context I only want to be able to use `timeDilation` from the `scheduler.dart` library, and nothing else. Since schedulers are pretty low-level thing this makes sense to not pollute the namespace. There's also `hide` that has the opposite effect (only hides certain declarations)