# How to cancel the animation on opening and closing the navigation drawer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-animation

I have to speed up my application integration testing. for that, I want to cancel the animation on opening and closing the navigation drawer in the flutter. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: hi, Welcome to SO. Please [Read How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate to other page without animation Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874272/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-without-animation-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to cancel/disable all the animations completely. But you can make it faster or slower by setting `timeDilation`.

To make the animation faster

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

void main() {
  timeDilation = 0.001;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: For more informations : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116814/slowing-down-animations-in-flutter-globally